# How to use "data" element of a DITA map in generated AEM Site output

Tags: java, xml, adobe, aem

I'm quite new to AEM Guides/XML Documentation and I am currently trying to figure out how to get "data" elements from a DITA Map in the generated AEM Site.

To clarify, the DITA Map has the following structure:

```
<map>

   <title>XXX</title>
   <data>

      <image id="logo" href="GUID-123asd123.jpg" ></image>

      <xref format="txt" href="GUID-asd123qwe.txt" id="copyright">

   </data>

   <topicref ... ></topicref>

</map>
```

I want to use contents of "data" element in AEM Site pages, e.g.:

- show the brand logo on top of each page according to the "image" tag in Map
- show the copyright disclaimer in footer section of each page according to "xref" tag in Map

I did some experiments with custom Design template for AEM Site preset and custom mappings between DITA elements and AEM components (elementmapping.xml), but I'm not able to understand which is the correct way to use "data" elements in my pages.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a way?